# ¿Como puedo bind value en bucle en blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

intento de añadir una valor en mi modelo con una bucle como asi

```
           @for (int i = 0; i < MailList.Count; i++)
            {
               <InputText @bind-Value="MailList[i]"/>
            }
```

y obtengo una error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported.
> FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields,
> properties) of an object

no comprendo de donde viene

Answer (score 0):

El problema tienes en el acceso a un elemento de colección "MailList[i]".
El @bind-Value lo que te permite es crear el binding de una propieda y controlar sus cambios. Este uso es muy habitual en los formularios para verificar email, telefono, url, etc.
Pero lo que haces tu, es mostrar un monton de filas editables. Si cada fila seria una propiedad - no hay problema, pero como no es asi, estas accediendo a la lista y en Blazor el componente InputText no tiene capacidad de permitir de hacer un binding completo de algo que no sea una propiedad o un objeto con sus propiedades.
En este caso lo mejor es descartar el InputText de Blazor y utilizar el  tradicional de HTML. O crear un componente tuyo a medida donde le pasarias la lista y el numero del elemento, asi la gestión la realizarias dentro del componente que has personalizado.

Asi que si no utilizas binding te funcionaria y si quieres utilizar binding de elementos de la lista - haz tu propio componente.

Aqui tienes el ejemplo que te funcionaria si no usas binding:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<EditForm Model="this">
    @for (int i = 0; i < MailList.Count; i++)
    {
        <input value="@MailList[i]" />
    }
</EditForm>

@code {
    public List<string> MailList { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
}
```